# How do you find out which database links are used in queries for the Oracle RDBMS?

Tags: database, oracle

I would like to find out if any and which database links are being used, for a schema, and in which tables. Is it possible via the data dictionary somehow?

Is this possible with the Oracle RDBMS?

Comment: Will you be accessing the data dictionary as a DBA user? Normal users generally don't have access to all dictionary objects, so this will be an important factor.

Comment: It will be possible to accses via a DBA user. However i prefer to do it as a normal user if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will show you any database links set up on the database:

```
select * from dba_db_links;
```

You would then have to search for any queries or objects using the db link by doing a text search of them for the link syntax `<tablename>@<dblink name>`

Comment: It should be mentioned that DBA_DB_LINKS will not be available to normal users unless O7_DICTIONARY_ACCESSIBILITY = TRUE, and the user has SELECT_ANY_TABLE. Otherwise it will usually only be available to DBA users. However, all users can access USER_DB_LINKS, but that would only be sufficient if the query in question only uses dblinks from the user's own schema.

Comment: I prefer not to do text searches. Are there any packages available to tell me the table references? I have created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467735/do-any-parsers-exist-for-the-oracle-dml-table-reference

Answer (score 4):

I know the answer by Dougman is accepted and accurate. But here is some more information.

If the user is not a DBA user, it will not have access to DBA_DB_LINKS. Also, USER_DB_LINKS will display the db links created by the current user, so that won't list all the DB links that the user has access to.

You can use ALL_DB_LINKS to get the links that the user has access to.

```
select * from all_db_links;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can first edit all sql code of a schema:
ex:

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(object_type, object_name, owner)
  FROM all_OBJECTS
  WHERE (OWNER = 'your schema name');
```

and then search in the result the pattern of the db_link, which looks like `@dblink_name`.